# How can I read serialised php data with perl

Tags: php, perl

I have a data file that contains nothing more but serialised data from PHP (specifically the serialize keyword). Thing is I now need to read it and work with in some perl code.

How do I do this?

This is a dumbed down example of how data is getting into the data files:

```
$ar = ["category" => "Ser", "dewey" => "001.12", "title" => "Doesn't Matter"];
$sar = serialize($ar); 
file_put_contents("data.ser", $sar);
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [PHP::Serialization](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?PHP%3a%3aSerialization) from CPAN.

An example from the site:

```
use PHP::Serialization qw(serialize unserialize);
my $encoded = serialize({ a => 1, b => 2});
my $hashref = unserialize($encoded);
```

If you have control over how the data is written out to the data files, consider using a different method, json encoded data is more terse and xml more descriptive. If you're able to do this, you might have more reliable modules that you can use; plus you should be able to load/manipulate your data from other platforms/languages too.